# Print random line from txt file?

Tags: python, random

I'm using random.randint to generate a random number, and then assigning that number to a variable. Then I want to print the line with the number I assigned to the variable, but I keep getting the error:

> list index out of range

Here's what I tried:

```
f = open(filename. txt)
lines = f.readlines() 

rand_line = random. randint(1,10)
print lines[rand_line]
```

Comment: How many lines does your file have? (Or rather, how many elements are in the list `lines`)

Comment: Try randint(0 , len(lines))

Comment: @A.Kot That can still go wrong.

Comment: @UnholySheep 10

Answer (score 9):

You want to use `random.choice`

```
import random
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(random.choice(lines))
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a random line without loading the whole file in memory you can use [Reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) (with sample size of 1):

```
from random import randrange    

def get_random_line(afile, default=None):
    """Return a random line from the file (or default)."""
    line = default
    for i, aline in enumerate(afile, start=1):
        if randrange(i) == 0:  # random int [0..i)
            line = aline
    return line


with open('filename.txt') as f:
    print(get_random_line(f))
```

This algorithm runs in `O(n)` time using `O(1)` additional space.

Answer (score 0):

This code is correct, assuming that you meant to pass a string to `open` function, and that you have no space after the dot...
However, be careful to the indexing in Python, namely it starts at 0 and not 1, and then ends at `len(your_list)-1`.

Using `random.choice` is better, but if you want to follow your idea it would rather be:

```
import random
with open('name.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    random_int = random.randint(0,len(lines)-1)
    print lines[random_int]
```

Since `randint` includes both boundary, you must look until `len(lines)-1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open(filename. txt)
lines = f.readlines() 

rand_line = random.randint(0, (len(lines) - 1))  # https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint
print lines[rand_line]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your code to achieve this without an error.

```
f = open(filename. txt)
lines = f.readlines() 

rand_line = random. randint(0,len(lines)-1) # this should make it work
print lines[rand_line]
```

This way the index is not out of range.